# AVPlayer (or AVAudioSession?) plays after I leave the ViewController, and when I return two are then playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avplayer, avaudiosession

I have a viewController that streams audio from the web. When I leave that page of my app, the audio keeps playing (this is good). However, when I go back, the viewdidload method creates a second audioplayer. I can do this over and over until I have so many AVplayers. It sounds incredibly echo-y. Here is all my relevant code.

```
#import "ListenViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVPlayerItem.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "RSPlayPauseButton.h"

@interface ListenViewController () <AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AVAudioSessionDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayer *player;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayerItem *playerItem;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RSPlayPauseButton *playPauseButton;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDate *now;



@end

@implementation ListenViewController

static int min = -2;

-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    //[self.player pause];
    min = -2;
}

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /*
    if ([AVAudioSession sharedInstance].isInputAvailable) {
        NSLog(@"XXXXXXXXX");
    }
     */

    NSURL *streamingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL.m3u"];

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:streamingURL];
    self.playerItem = playerItem;

    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    [player setAllowsExternalPlayback:NO];

    CMTime tm = CMTimeMake(1, 1);

    [player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:tm
                                         queue:dispatch_get_main_queue() usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {
                                             /*
                                              NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                                              [DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:mmm"];
                                              NSLog(@"%@",[DateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
                                              */
                                             if (!self.now) {
                                                 self.now = [NSDate date];
                                             }

                                                 /*
                                                 NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
                                                 NSTimeInterval interval = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self.now];
                                                 self.interval += 0.01;
                                                 interval -= (10 * self.rw2);
                                                 interval -= (60 * self.rw3);
                                                 interval += (10 * self.ff2);

                                                 self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", interval];
                                                 NSLog(@"INTERVAL: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.interval]);
                                                  */

                                             if (CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime) >= 0) {
                                             self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime)];

                                                 NSTimeInterval time = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime);

                                                 //int min = time/60;

                                                 int sec = lroundf(time) % 60;




                                                 if (sec == 0) {
                                                     ++min;
                                                 }
                                                 NSLog(@"sec: %d", sec);
                                                 // update your UI with timeLeft
                                                 self. timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d", min,sec];
                                             }
                                         }];


    [self setPlayer:player];

    [player play];


    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

    if (!self.playPauseButton) {
        self.playPauseButton = [[RSPlayPauseButton alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        self.playPauseButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:155.0/255.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        self.playPauseButton.animationStyle = RSPlayPauseButtonAnimationStyleSplitAndRotate;
        self.playPauseButton.paused = NO;
        [self.playPauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playPauseButtonDidPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    [self.view addSubview:self.playPauseButton];
}

- (IBAction)rewind:(id)sender
{
    //NSLog(@"currenttime: %f", CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime));
    //NSLog(@"timescale: %d", self.player.currentTime.timescale);
    CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMake(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime) - 1.0, 1);
    CMTime zero = CMTimeMake(1, 2);
    if (CMTimeGetSeconds(cmTime) > CMTimeGetSeconds(zero)) {
    [self.player.currentItem seekToTime:cmTime];
        NSLog(@"!");
    }
    NSLog(@"RW");
}


- (IBAction)rewind2:(id)sender
{
    /*
    CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime) - 10.0, self.player.currentTime.timescale);
    CMTime zero = CMTimeMake(0, 10000);
    if (CMTimeGetSeconds(cmTime) > CMTimeGetSeconds(zero)) {
        [self.player.currentItem seekToTime:cmTime];
        self.rw2 += 1;
        NSLog(@"RW2!");
    }
     */
    NSLog(@"RW2");
    CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime) - 10.0, self.player.currentTime.timescale);
    CMTime zero = CMTimeMake(1, 2);
    NSLog(@"cmTime: %f", CMTimeGetSeconds(cmTime));
    NSLog(@"zero: %f", CMTimeGetSeconds(zero));
    if (CMTimeGetSeconds(cmTime) > CMTimeGetSeconds(zero)) {
        [self.player.currentItem seekToTime:cmTime];
        NSLog(@"!");
    } else {
        [self rewindAll];
    }
}


- (IBAction)rewind3:(id)sender
{
    CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime) - 60.0, self.player.currentTime.timescale);
    CMTime zero = CMTimeMake(0, 10000);
    if (CMTimeGetSeconds(cmTime) > CMTimeGetSeconds(zero)) {
        [self.player.currentItem seekToTime:cmTime];
        NSLog(@"RW3!");
    }
    NSLog(@"RW3");
}

- (void) rewindAll
{
    CMTime one = CMTimeMake(1, 1);
    [self.player.currentItem seekToTime:one];
}

- (IBAction)fastForward:(id)sender
{

    CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime) + 5.0, self.player.currentTime.timescale);
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeInterval interval = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self.now];

    CMTime seekingCM = CMTimeMake(interval, 1);

    if (CMTimeGetSeconds(cmTime) < CMTimeGetSeconds(seekingCM)) {
        [self.player.currentItem seekToTime:cmTime];
    }

}

- (IBAction)fastForward2:(id)sender
{

    CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime) + 10.0, self.player.currentTime.timescale);
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeInterval interval = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self.now];

    CMTime seekingCM = CMTimeMake(interval, 1);

    if (CMTimeGetSeconds(cmTime) < CMTimeGetSeconds(seekingCM)) {
        [self.player.currentItem seekToTime:cmTime];
        NSLog(@"FF2!");
    } else {
        [self fastForward3:nil];
    }
}

- (IBAction)fastForward3:(id)sender
{

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"FIRSTDATE: %@", self.now);
    NSTimeInterval interval = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self.now];
    interval -= 0.5f;
    NSLog(@"INT: %f", interval);

    CMTime seekingCM = CMTimeMake(interval, 1);


    /*
    NSTimeInterval interval = self.interval - 1.0;
    CMTime seekingCM = CMTimeMake(interval, 1);
    [self.player.currentItem seekToTime:seekingCM];
     */
    //CMTime seekingCM = CMTimeMake(self.interval, 1);
    [self.player.currentItem seekToTime:seekingCM];
    NSLog(@"FF3!");
}

- (NSTimeInterval)currentPlaybackTime
{
    return CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentItem.currentTime);
}

- (void)setCurrentPlaybackTime:(NSTimeInterval)time
{
    CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(time, NSEC_PER_SEC);
    [self.player.currentItem seekToTime:cmTime];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [self.playPauseButton sizeToFit];
    self.playPauseButton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.view.frame.size.height / 1.2);
}


- (void)playPauseButtonDidPress:(RSPlayPauseButton *)playPauseButton
{
    [playPauseButton setPaused:!playPauseButton.isPaused animated:YES];
    if (playPauseButton.isPaused) {
        [self.player pause];
    }
    else {
        [self.player play];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

By the way, there is a UIlabel that gives the current time of the player, but if I leave the page and go back, the label automatically starts again at 00:00. This is because it's giving the current time of the new AVPlayer. Is there a way to make it give the current time of the original AVPlayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a singleton object to control a `AVPlayer`, so no matter how many view controllers you have they all would communicate with this one player controller. So basically I'd advise you to move all the code you have in `viewDidLoad` to some `MYPlayerController` singleton class.

Comment: @Jameson can you post the solution?

Comment: What I ended up doing was making a Singleton of that audioplayer, and rather than creating a new one, I just got the singleton.

Answer (score 0):

here is my view controller from swift, if it can help you, will be fine, I have implemented all radio stuff there:

[swift view controller](http://pastebin.com/6Yz61NW7)

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do it without creating new instances. How do I check if they're already created, because for THAT viewController, when the VC loads, all of it's properties are nil. The AVPlayer that is playing belonged to the last VC. Right?

Comment: no, you need create new instances that right, but create them without definitions, so it will be a reference to private member, not new variable

Comment: Huh. Well I took out the definitions (e.g., `AVPlayerItem * playerItem = ...`, so it just says `playerItem = ...`), and I'm still facing the same problem. Taking out those definitions created a lot of errors in my code, because `playerItem` and `player` were never defined, so I had to refer to them as the properties `self.playerItem` and `self.player` instead.

Comment: well, sorry, my bad, I have the same radio stream app, and I just overrided there viewDidLoad method like that:
 "override func viewDidAppear(anumated: Bool)", don't know how it is in obj-C, sorry

Comment: No problem, thanks a ton for trying. Can you post what you did in swift or whatever language and I'll try to translate it?